# how to barge-in on a <foreach> element

Tags: ivr, vxml, voicexml, ucma

I'm using Microsoft's UCMA 4.0 SDK to build a basic VXML IVR system.  When I have a normal prompt using the default system voice, you can 'barge-in' by pressing any DTMF key:

```
<prompt>Your credit card number is 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4</prompt>
```

However I'd like to use the customers own voice.  To do this i build up an array of individual audio prompts, and play them back using a  loop:

```
<prompt>
    <foreach item="i" array="BuildCardPrompt()">
        <audio expr="i"/>
    </foreach>
</prompt>
```

Problem is that now I am unable to 'barge-in' and interrupt the  loop.  Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The VoiceXML spec indicates that barge-in should work with a foreach loop. Might be a platform issue and I do not have the Microsoft platform to test it out.  You could try wrapping the audio element in a prompt element like this and see if it makes a difference.

```
  <foreach item="i" array="BuildCardPrompt()">
    <prompt>
      <audio expr="i"/>
      <break/>
    </prompt>
  </foreach>
```

Another alternative is to dynamically create the VoiceXML that contains the sequential series of prompts.